# Component not updating in the current view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, requirejs

Working on Javascript based hybrid application, it uses require.js and knockout.

**Scenerio:**

- My screen has a component and an update button.
- by default the component has some local data, fetched from JSON.
- On click of button, app will make request to external URL and fetch
     back the data
- The updated data should be reflected to the component

**Issue:**
I  am able to see the dummy data on my component properly. On click of button the data is fetched from server properly, however the view is NOT updated.
What can be the reason and possible solution?

**Workaround**
If I switch view and come back then the data is updated in the component.

```js
define(['text!../seriesOneData.json', 'knockout', 'jquery', 'appController', 'ojs/ojtimeline'],
        function (file,  ko, $, app) {

            function DashboardViewModel() {
                var self = this;
                self.currentDateString = "Feb 1, 2010";
                self.currentDate = new Date(self.currentDateString).getTime();
                var content = JSON.parse(file);
                self.series = ko.observableArray(content)();
                self.buttonClick = function () {
                    console.log('button clicked');
                    var settings = {

                        "url": "http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/cookbook/dataVisualizations/timeline/basicTimeline/seriesOneData.json",
                        "method": "GET"
                    };
                    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        self.series = response;
                        console.log(self.series);
                        
                    });
                }
      );
```

```html
    <div id="tline"
         data-bind='ojComponent: {
  component: "ojTimeline",
  minorAxis: {
  scale: "weeks",
    zoomOrder: ["months", "weeks", "days"]
  },
  majorAxis: {
    scale: "quarters"
  },
  start: new Date("Jan 1, 2010").toISOString(),
  end: new Date("Dec 31, 2010").toISOString(),
  selectionMode: "single",
  referenceObjects: [{value: currentDate}],
  selection: ["e4"],
  series: [{ 
    id: "s1",
    emptyText: "No Data.",
    items: series,
    label: "Oracle Events"
  }],
  overview: {
    rendered: "off"
  }                                         
},
attr: {"aria-label": "Single Series Timeline Demo. Current date is " + currentDateString}'
         style="width: '100%';height: 380px"></div>
         <button id= "button"
            data-bind="click: buttonClick, 
                       ojComponent: { component: 'ojButton', label: 'Update Events' }">         
         
         </div>        
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting your own observable instead of updating its value

```
$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    self.series = response;
    ...
}
```

should be:

```
$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    self.series(response);
    ...
}
```

Of course you're also doing something strange where the observable is first created:

```
self.series = ko.observableArray(content)();
```

I don't believe you want the extra parenthesis there at the end. That's going to discard the observable you just created and replace it with the flat value that it was created from. Which is nonsense.

Comment: I get error if I apply both changes, function observable() {
        if (arguments.length > 0) {
            // Write

            // Ignore writes if the value hasn't changed
            if (observable.isDifferent(observable[observ…

Comment: On what line does the error occur? Though I'm not sure I can do much without a full reproducible example. A jsfiddle would be helpful

Comment: self.series(response);